# Multimedia upload error in my wordpress job board plugin

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, media

I have the below code in my plugin. Admin is meant to be able to insert `funding_amount`, `funding_deadline`, and `funding_multimedia_field` from the dashboard if the resource category chosen is funding. `funding_amount`, and `funding_deadline` work as expected but the file upload is not working as no file is saved in my WordPress media gallery.

`custom_resources_handle_file_upload` is the function to handle the upload. Can someone please, help me check this code and proffer a solution? Thank you.

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Resources Plugin
Description: A custom WordPress plugin for managing and displaying resources.
Version: 1.0
*/

// Define categories and their associated fields with field types
$category_fields = array(
    'job' => array(
        'job_location' => array(
            'label' => 'Job Location',
            'type' => 'text',
            // Use 'text' field type for text input
        ),
        'job_type' => array(
            'label' => 'Job Type',
            'type' => 'select',
            // Use 'select' field type for dropdown select
            'options' => array(
                'full_time' => 'Full Time',
                'part_time' => 'Part Time',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'internship' => array(
        'internship_location' => array(
            'label' => 'Internship Location',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        'internship_duration' => array(
            'label' => 'Internship Duration (in weeks)',
            'type' => 'number',
            // Use 'number' field type for numeric input
        ),
    ),
    'funding' => array(
        'funding_amount' => array(
            'label' => 'Funding Amount',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        'funding_deadline' => array(
            'label' => 'Funding Deadline',
            'type' => 'date',
            // Use 'date' field type for date input
        ),
        'funding_multimedia_field' => array(
            'label' => 'Funding Multimedia Field',
            'type' => 'file',
            // Use 'file' field type for multimedia input
        ),
    ),
);

// Register custom post type
function custom_resources_register_post_type()
{
    register_post_type(
        'resources',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Resources',
                'singular_name' => 'Resource',
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
            // 'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-resources', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/custom-resources.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}

add_action('init', 'custom_resources_register_post_type');

// Register custom taxonomies based on the structure of $category_fields
// Register custom taxonomy
function custom_resources_register_taxonomy()
{
    $category_labels = array(
        'name' => 'Resource Categories',
        'singular_name' => 'Resource Category',
        'menu_name' => 'Resource Categories',
        'all_items' => 'All Categories',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Category',
        'view_item' => 'View Category',
        'update_item' => 'Update Category',
        // 'add_new_item' => 'Add New Category',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Category Name',
        'search_items' => 'Search Categories',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular Categories',
        'not_found' => 'No Categories found',
        'no_terms' => 'No Categories',
        'items_list' => 'Categories list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Categories list navigation',
    );

    $category_args = array(
        'labels' => $category_labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resource-category'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('resource_category', 'resources', $category_args);

    // Assign terms to the custom taxonomy
    global $category_fields;

    foreach ($category_fields as $category => $fields) {
        // Check if the term already exists
        $term_exists = term_exists($category, 'resource_category');

        if (!$term_exists) {
            // If the term doesn't exist, add it
            wp_insert_term($category, 'resource_category');
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'custom_resources_register_taxonomy');


// Add custom fields based on category
function custom_resources_add_custom_fields()
{
    add_meta_box('resource_category', 'Resource Category', 'custom_resources_render_category', 'resources', 'normal', 'high');
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'custom_resources_add_custom_fields');

// Render category dropdown and dynamic fields
function custom_resources_render_category($post)
{
    // Retrieve the selected category
    $selected_category = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resource_category', true);

    // Get the list of categories and fields
    global $category_fields;

    echo '<label for="resource_category">Category:</label>';
    echo '<select name="resource_category" id="resource_category-select">';
    echo '<option value="">Select Category</option>';

    foreach ($category_fields as $category => $fields) {
        $selected = ($selected_category === $category) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($category) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html(ucfirst($category)) . '</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';

    // Display the fields based on the selected category
    echo '<div id="custom-fields-container">';

    foreach ($category_fields as $category => $fields) {
        $style = ($selected_category === $category) ? 'style="display: block;"' : 'style="display: none;"';
        echo '<div class="custom-fields" data-category="' . esc_attr($category) . '" ' . $style . '>';

        foreach ($fields as $field_key => $field_settings) {
            $field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field_key, true);
            $field_type = $field_settings['type'];
            $field_label = $field_settings['label'];

            echo '<label for="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '">' . esc_html($field_label) . ':</label>';

            if ($field_type === 'select') {
                echo '<select name="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '">';
                foreach ($field_settings['options'] as $option_value => $option_label) {
                    $selected = ($field_value === $option_value) ? 'selected' : '';
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($option_value) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html($option_label) . '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            } elseif ($field_type === 'number') {
                echo '<input type="number" name="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '" value="' . esc_attr($field_value) . '">';
            } elseif ($field_type === 'date') {
                echo '<input type="date" name="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '" value="' . esc_attr($field_value) . '">';
            } elseif ($field_type === 'file') {
                echo '<input type="file" name="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '">';
                if ($field_value) {
                    echo '<p><a href="' . esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url($field_value)) . '">View File</a></p>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<input type="text" name="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field_key) . '" value="' . esc_attr($field_value) . '">';
            }
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

// Save custom fields
function custom_resources_save_custom_fields($post_id)
{
    // Save the selected category
    if (isset($_POST['resource_category'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'resource_category', sanitize_text_field($_POST['resource_category']));
    }

    // Save the fields based on the selected category
    $selected_category = get_post_meta($post_id, 'resource_category', true);
    global $category_fields;

    if (array_key_exists($selected_category, $category_fields)) {
        $fields = $category_fields[$selected_category];
        foreach ($fields as $field_key => $field_settings) {
            if (isset($_POST[$field_key])) {
                $field_type = $field_settings['type'];
                $field_value = $_POST[$field_key];

                // Sanitize and handle specific field types
                if ($field_type === 'select') {
                    // Ensure the selected option is one of the predefined options
                    if (isset($field_settings['options'][$field_value])) {
                        update_post_meta($post_id, $field_key, sanitize_text_field($field_value));
                    }
                } elseif ($field_type === 'number') {
                    // Ensure the input is a numeric value
                    if (is_numeric($field_value)) {
                        update_post_meta($post_id, $field_key, sanitize_text_field($field_value));
                    }
                } elseif ($field_type === 'date') {
                    // Ensure the input is a valid date
                    if (strtotime($field_value)) {
                        update_post_meta($post_id, $field_key, sanitize_text_field($field_value));
                    }
                } elseif ($field_type === 'file') {
                    // Handle file uploads
                    $attachment_id = custom_resources_handle_file_upload($field_key);
                    if ($attachment_id) {
                        update_post_meta($post_id, $field_key, $attachment_id);
                    }
                } else {
                    // For text input, sanitize as text
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $field_key, sanitize_text_field($field_value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'custom_resources_save_custom_fields');

// Helper function to handle file uploads
// Helper function to handle file uploads
function custom_resources_handle_file_upload($field_key)
{
    error_log('$_FILES contents: ' . print_r($_FILES, true));
    if (isset($_FILES[$field_key])) {

        $file = $_FILES[$field_key];
        $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);

        // Upload the file
        $file_info = wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides);

        if ($file_info && !isset($file_info['error'])) {
            // Create an attachment post
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $file_info['type'],
                'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($file_info['file']),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
            );

            $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_info['file']);

            if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $file_info['file']);
                wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

                return $attachment_id;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: it's very likely the problem is somewhere in `custom_resources_handle_file_upload` but there's no error reporting or error checking in that function, it just returns `false` at the end. Can you do error checking to identify which part of that function is failing? is `$file_info` bad? what if `$attachment_id` is an error object?

Comment: @TomJNowell, thank you for the response. I observed that the function attached to the save_post action is not being fired. `add_action('save_post', 'custom_resources_save_custom_fields')`. I also added this     `error_log('reached here');` inside the `custom_resources_save_custom_fields` function. I am still new to plugin development. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: could it be that `save_post` is innapropriate because it's not a post? It's a `resources`?

Comment: Kindly help with a solution. Resources is a custom post type and I want to call a PHP function when the publish or update button is clicked. In essence, I want to upload a media file in the form. Thank you

Comment: There's no need to ping I get notifications in the top bar when I visit the site, if this is urgent then you might want to look at finding a contractor/freelancer offsite, WPSE is a community of unpaid volunteers across many timezones and fields. If `save_post` does not run consider changing the hook used to this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/

Comment: Well. I came here because I believed that I could get help. If you are willing to help, then please go ahead. You could easily help with a tested code snippet. I have tried using save_post_resources with the same result